# Gitignore all non-matching a particular pattern

Tags: git, glob, gitignore

I've attempted to use the following in my `.gitignore` to no avail (files are being ignored, regardless of the `!`):

```
*
!(CODE_OF_CONDUCT|CONTRIBUTING|README).md
!.(editorconfig|github|gitignore|prettierrc|versionrc|vscode)
!(docs|example|LICENSE|src)
!(package|package-lock|(tsconfig.*)).json
```

Is there a way that I can get the above to work? That is, to match and exclude all except those that align with the described patterns.

Comment: I don't see regex referenced at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: I only tagged with `regex` because globs encapsulate regexes. Removed the tag anyways per your comment.

Comment: Well your first line is `*` which translates to "ignore anything except slash" according to the docs. Is that desired?

Comment: Where, specifically, did you get the idea that "globs encapsulate regex"?

Comment: The goal is to ignore everything except for those specified via patterns in lines 2-5.

Comment: @jthill Glad I'm not the only one... Globs are more like a stranger that passed by regex on the street one day and really liked their shoelaces so they went home and ordered a knock-off brand.

Comment: @jthill that's a great question. I honestly cannot recount, although this now seems to be a misconception. Apologies for bringing regexes into this question. Hopefully my removal of the tag helps ensure the correct discoverability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `.gitignore` uses filename globs, not regular expressions (and afaik also not *extended* globbing). As a result, the parentheses, the 'pipe symbol' (`|`), etc. have no special meaning and are interpreted as part of the filenames.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to express the `or` within the patterns. You need to do something along the lines of this (I did not include all original files):

```
*
!CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
!CONTRIBUTING.md
!README.md
!.editorconfig
!.github
!.gitignore
!tsconfig.*.json
```

If applicable, you can maybe group some files by common name parts, e.g.

```
!.git*
```

or by their extension, like

```
!*.md
```

and/or restrict the pattern to uppercase filenames

```
![ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*.md
```

(Note that this is not the same as `[A-Z]*`, since standard glob sorts `AaBbCc` etc., so the latter means all upper- and lowercase characters except lowercase `z`).

You could also 'group' by sub-directories,  but that does not seem applicable in your case.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

---

Edit: an indirect way of doing what you want, is using a more compact syntax when you generate the file (credits to @jthill):

```
printf %s\\n \!{package,package-lock,tsconfig.*}.json >>.gitignore
```

However, this will not make the resulting file shorter.

Comment: Is there any way to reuse the extensions / prefixes, as to avoid bloat. Or is there no way to express the `or` pattern?

Comment: You can do it when you generate the file, `printf %s\\n \!{package,package-lock,tsconfig.*}.json >>.gitignore`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to express the `or` within the patterns. You can 'group' by extension, sub-directories, or common name parts (e.g. `.git*`), but not in the way which you tried.

Comment: Gotcha. @buddemat –– can you please add that to the answer & I'll give it the green check :)